# First scheduleLocalNotification not being sent

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

I have an set of Local Notifications that I have scheduled to be sent out by setting a fire date on each one from iterating through an array. The problem is for some reason the first notification is not being sent, all the others are set and sent fine. This is the code:

```
var notifi = 0
var firstDate = NSDate()

        let dateArrays = Array(1...3)

                for _ in dateArrays{

                        if notifi < 64 {

                        firstDate = firstDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(10)

                        notification.category = "FIRST_CATEGORY"
                        notification.alertBody = "It's time to look away now!"
                        notification.fireDate = firstDate

                        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
                        notifi = notifi + 1

                        }else {
                            print("local notifications limit has been reached")
                                }
                            }
```